# How to configure beitmemcached on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, memcached

I installed memcached for windows, downloaded & built beitmemcached.dll

Now how to start using it? Shall I create a console App to setup a client with those lines of code only:

//Set up a client. 
            MemcachedClient.Setup("MyCache", new string[] { "localhost" });

Then my applications can access the above cache entry using:

MemcachedClient cache = MemcachedClient.GetInstance("MyCache");

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a Console Application & another ASP.NET MVC 3 app.

In the console application you setup the client:

//Set up a client. 
MemcachedClient.Setup("MyCache", new string[] { "localhost" });

Then, I get the instance:

MemcachedClient cache = MemcachedClient.GetInstance("MyCache");

Then, I start adding/retrieving data.

In the ASP.NET MVC code, I setup the same client inside Global.asax.cs

After that, I get the instance of the client and start adding/retrieving data.

You will notice that "MyCache" will be shared among the Console App and ASP.NET MVC.

That's very cool!

HTH